# How to store custom object in Variable similar to Tkinter's Variable object

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter, I attempted to use the `Variable` object to store custom objects. However, retrieving from the variable always returns a `str` object of the custom object's `__repr__()` function as can be seen from the snippet below.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "repr"
        

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
variable = tk.Variable()
variable.set(Test())
print(variable.get())
print(type(variable.get()))


#output
repr
<class 'str'>
```

As I am using the Variable with `trace_add` and a callback function which then utilises the object I stored in the `Variable`, I would need it to store the variable rather than just the string repr. However, tkinter's existing `Var` objects do not include one for objects. Is there an existing way to accomplish this, or will this require subclassing `Variable` or using a separate storage mechanism and utilising trace to trigger access?

Comment: What do you mean by *custom object*? And what do you want to trace?

Comment: I am adding the trace to the `tkinter.Variable` object and using the variable in an entry. The trace itself is working correctly as expected of a Variable object, but the actual stored value is the `__repr__` return value rather than the object. It doesn't seem like it is specifically user-defined classes but rather classes in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by subclassing `tk.Variable` and overwriting/creating functions. Admittedly, I don't know enough about how the trace function works to know if there is a better way to do it, but this has worked for my needs.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        pass
        

import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

class CustomVar(tk.Variable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.current = None
        
    def set(self, value: object):
        self.current = value
        # calling set on super to trigger write mode traces
        super().set(value)
        
    def get(self):
        # similarly for triggering read mode traces
        super().get()
        return self.current
    
def callback(*args):
    print(variable.get())
    print(type(variable.get()))
    print(variable.get().value)
    
root = tk.Tk()
variable = CustomVar()
variable.trace_add(mode="write", callback=callback)

tk.Button(root, text="Write", command=lambda: variable.set(Test(randint(0,10)))).pack()
root.mainloop()
```